# Asp.Net C# invoke single validator

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation

I am having problems trying to invoke just one validator on it own, I know how to call on all validators to perform checks on buttons click events, by using `Page.Validate()` but how can I invoke lets say `mySingledOutValidator` I tried `mySingledOutValidator.Validate()` but that's not gonna work individual controls don't have `.validate()`

I need the following to be true:

- Get a single validation to happen
- In C# Asp.Net
- .net 2.0 framework

If the above is not possible I do not mind looking into javascript alternatives.
If you can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: .net `2.5` framework or .net `3.5` framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Group Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx). You can assign a validator a `validationgroup` value, and then explicitly validate that group, which can contain 1 or more validators.

```
Page.Validate("MyGroup");
```

You can also check the validation status of each validator explicitly using `IsValid` property, assuming validation has already taken place.

Comment: Can I do `ValidationGroup="Group1 Group2"` ?

Comment: No you can't do that. Validators can only belong to one group. You could make it work, but I think it would be better to avoid this scenario. You could always have one validator for each group if necessary (although not ideal). It's an easier problem to solve server-side, you just call Validate multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

According [this article](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-manage-asp.net-validation-from-javascript-with-jquery.aspx):

```
function ValidatorValidate(val, validationGroup, event)
```

With jquery validators:

> And in case I wanted to force the validation I should have written:
>   `ValidatorValidate($("#<%= valEncOtherMimeTypeRequired.ClientID %>")[0]);`

Comment: This is the method .NET uses for client-side validation when the `validationgroup` attributes are set, and a button/submit with a matching `validationgroup` is pressed. It shouldn't be necessary to call it directly.

Comment: @TheCodeKing The OP is asking about javascript alternatives for single validator check. This is it.

Comment: Wasn't meant as a negative, just highlighting that `ValidatorValidate` is used by the group validation implementation by default.